# Android application in eclipse

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have got a problem in AndriodMenifest.xml in eclipse. The error is in

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

It says that 
`<uses-sdk>` tag should specify a target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later versions,compatibility behaviors may be enabled) with `android:targetSdkVersion="?"`

Though the API level of android is 8,i am getting this error.How to solve it?

Comment: Set android:targetSdkVersion="8"

Answer (score 0):

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml (use the source view) and set the targetSdkVersion to 8

(technically, it should be set to the highest version of android you have verified your application works on, it is used to determine what backward compatibility features should be used)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `android:targetSdkVersion="8"` attribute to the `uses-sdk` tag. If you just want to get rid of the warning, that will do it.

But it is always considered good practice to include `android:targetSdkVersion`

Google have provided very good description on it check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

for example, If your min SDK was 8, but your target SDK was 14, you are telling android that while there's no reason it shouldn't work on version 8, you've only tested on 14. Therefore, if there any compatibility settings to enable between level 8 and 14, they can be set.

Answer (score 0):

check wheter you defined sdk in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

also check your **default.properties** file for this

```
target=android-8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
```

you need to specify both.